# Do moles of an acid and base have to be exactly equal for neutralization to occur?

Tags: physical-chemistry, stoichiometry

I'm supposed to prove whether a statement is true or false:

> 5 moles of sodium hydroxide will neutralize $\ce{250 cm^3}$ of hydrochloric acid of concentration $\ce{10 mol/dm^3}$.

So far, I've balanced the equation: $\ce{HCl + NaOH -> NaCl + H2O}$. I've also found the moles of $\ce{HCl}: 10/1000 \times 250 = \pu{2.5 moles}$.

Since the ratio of $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ is $1:1$, I don't have to multiply anything, but I don't know whether the statement's true or false. I thought since $5>2$. $5$, the statement's true, but I was told that in the answer key, the statement's false.

So, does the moles of the substance have to be exactly equal in order for neutralization to occur?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question lies in the concept of stoichiometry. The number of moles required of each reactant must be in proportion to it's stoichiometric coefficient in the balanced chemical equation.
So accordingly, the statement should be false.